# MySQL PDO Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am literally brand new to PHP PDO programming, so I am just learning things.
I am running into the following error from the attached code that I have stared at for hours, and just cannot see my mistake.

> Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I know that this is telling me that either I do not have the correct number of columns in the SQL statement or that I am passing the incorrect number of variables to the execute() statement.  But I cannot for the life of me find my mistake.

I need another pair of eyes from someone far more knowledgeable to find my error.

Can someone help?

Thank you very much,
Jeff

Here is the code:

```
        try {
         $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
                 $username, $password);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO stagewishes
                    (id,wisher_name,description)
                    VALUES (:id,:name,:description,
                            (select
                                  wishes.id,
                                  wishers.name,
                                  wishes.description
                                  from wishes
                                  left join wishers
                                  on wishes.wisher_id = wishers.id
                                  where wishes.wisher_id = '$search_desc'
                                  order by wishes.id))");

         $stmt->bindParam(":id",$v_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(":name",$v_wishername,PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(":description",$v_description,PDO::PARAM_STR);

         $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is returning **FOUR** fields/values into a context where only a **SINGLE** value is permitted.

```
INSERT INTO stagewishes
            (id,wisher_name,description)
             1     2           3
            VALUES (:id,:name,:description,(select ...)
                     1    2         3          4567...???
```

and your top-level insert has already been specified with only **THREE** fields for values, and yet you're trying to stuff in 4+.

In other words, learn to read the error messages: `Column count doesn't match value count`: 3 columns, 4+ values.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I have completely mis-understood what PDO is doing there then.  Here is what I was trying to do.  I have two tables where I do a left join on them to return the ID, Name and Description.  (That is the select statement you see there).  What I then want to do is take those returned column data and write it out to a 3rd table.  I thought I could pass the "SELECT" statement and it would populate the variables of :id, :name, and :description from the "SELECT" statement.

Comment: So, knowing that is what I wanted to do, how does one get information "from" one data source with PDO and then pass that returned data to another for "insert" into another table?

Comment: you can't insert into more than one table at a time.

Comment: Hi Marc.  I understand that.  Thank you.  I do only want to insert into one table.  I just want to pull data from two different tables, and then insert that information into the third.

Comment: that's fine, but you still have to produce a correct query for that. if you're telling the db to insert 3 values, then 3 values is all you're allowed to provide.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you Marc